# TypeORM One-To-Many and Many-To-One relationship with share table

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, typeorm

I'm using [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) and having a problem with these relationships.
[image: reigel gallarde]

The problem is with the `attributes` entity.

```
@Entity('Attributes')
export class AttributesEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => parentEntityHere, parent => parent.id)
    parent: parentEntityHere;
}
```

if you'll notice, I have `parentEntityHere`. How can I make it that it can be of `table1` or `table2` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity('Attributes')
export class AttributesEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(type => Tab1, tab1 => tab1.attributes)
    parent1: Tab1;

    @ManyToOne(type => Tab2, tab2 => tab2.attributes)
    parent2: Tab2;    
}
```

In this solution there'll be 2 foreign keys in attributes table one from tab1 and one from tab2. So it'll be easy to get all attributes for tab1 row and/or tab2 row. And in Attributes object there'll be both parents.

Comment: yes that is my first solution, and I thought I could simplify it. hence I have posted this because I was surprised I might have missed something.